# Exception has occured:MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method isLoading)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm flutter mobile app development, collecting notes from users functionality were introduced in my app for that i'm using html editor enhanced and i have implemented that notes field,

In this package, below issue has repeatedly occurs

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method isLoading on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_6)
I/flutter (10451): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:308
I/flutter (10451): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (10451): #1      InAppWebViewController.isLoading
in_app_webview_controller.dart:1425
I/flutter (10451): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (10451): #2      HtmlEditorController._evaluateJavascript
html_editor_controller_mobile.dart:260
I/flutter (10451): <asynchronous suspension>
```

```
                                Container(
                                          height: 250,
                                          child: HtmlEditor(
                                            otherOptions: const OtherOptions(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.white)),
                                            controller: controller,
                                            htmlToolbarOptions:
                                                const HtmlToolbarOptions(
                                                    dropdownBoxDecoration:
                                                        BoxDecoration(
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.white),
                                                    defaultToolbarButtons: [],
                                                    toolbarItemHeight: 0),
                                            htmlEditorOptions:
                                                HtmlEditorOptions(
                                              autoAdjustHeight: false,
                                              initialText: textController.text,
                                              hint: "",
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

Comment: Can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (though it's hard to know what the exact issue is from just your description):

If you have changed your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`, you can't just `hot refresh` your app. Instead, you'll need to rebuild/restart the app for the new packages to be loaded.

I think some of the "Related questions" describe the same issue.